# Spring web socket message broker failing tests

Tags: java, spring, websocket

I have difficulties integrating a web socket message broker into my existing spring project. I have a few fully functional repositories and services. However, when I try to wire up my stuff with a websocket configuration (which is automatically loaded from config.xml with a component scan), all my existing tests suddenly fail.

**WebSocketConfig**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableStompBrokerRelay("/topic/");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/main");
    }


}
```

**Test**

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:config.xml"})
public class CategoryDaoTest extends DomainTestBase {

    @Autowired
    private CategoryDao categoryDao;

    @Test
    public void testAdd() {
        int size = categoryDao.list().size();
        categoryDao.add(new Category(5L, "test-category", "lorem ipsum"));
        assertTrue (size < categoryDao.list().size());
    }

    @Test
    public void testUpdate() {
        Category category = new Category(5L, "test-category", "lorem ipsum");
        categoryDao.add(category);
        category.setTitle("updated");
        categoryDao.update(category);

        // verify actual update
        Category found = categoryDao.find(category.getId());
        assertEquals("updated", found.getTitle());
    }

    @Test
    public void testFind() {
        Category category = new Category(5L, "test-category", "lorem ipsum");
        categoryDao.add(category);
        Category found = categoryDao.find(category.getId());
        assertEquals(found, category);
    }

}
```

**Stacktrace**

```
Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@27c28e4e] to prepare test instance [org.myproject.service.dao.CategoryDaoTest@c6ee2d8]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:157)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:109)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:321)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:211)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:290)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:24)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:157)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:74)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:211)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:67)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'stompWebSocketHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/web/socket/config/annotation/DelegatingWebSocketMessageBrokerConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping]: Factory method 'stompWebSocketHandlerMapping' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'messageBrokerSockJsTaskScheduler' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/web/socket/config/annotation/DelegatingWebSocketMessageBrokerConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler]: Factory method 'messageBrokerSockJsTaskScheduler' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler.setRemoveOnCancelPolicy(Z)V
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:602)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1113)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1008)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:505)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:229)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:762)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:103)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:1)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(DelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:228)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.loadApplicationContext(TestContext.java:124)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:148)
    ... 35 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping]: Factory method 'stompWebSocketHandlerMapping' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'messageBrokerSockJsTaskScheduler' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/web/socket/config/annotation/DelegatingWebSocketMessageBrokerConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler]: Factory method 'messageBrokerSockJsTaskScheduler' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler.setRemoveOnCancelPolicy(Z)V
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:591)
    ... 51 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'messageBrokerSockJsTaskScheduler' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/web/socket/config/annotation/DelegatingWebSocketMessageBrokerConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler]: Factory method 'messageBrokerSockJsTaskScheduler' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler.setRemoveOnCancelPolicy(Z)V
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:602)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1113)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1008)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:505)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:229)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:292)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.DelegatingWebSocketMessageBrokerConfiguration$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$8bcc47d8.messageBrokerSockJsTaskScheduler(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurationSupport.stompWebSocketHandlerMapping(WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurationSupport.java:51)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.DelegatingWebSocketMessageBrokerConfiguration$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$8bcc47d8.CGLIB$stompWebSocketHandlerMapping$9(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.DelegatingWebSocketMessageBrokerConfiguration$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$8bcc47d8$$FastClassByCGLIB$$f696e179.invoke(<generated>)
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:215)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:280)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.DelegatingWebSocketMessageBrokerConfiguration$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$8bcc47d8.stompWebSocketHandlerMapping(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
    ... 52 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler]: Factory method 'messageBrokerSockJsTaskScheduler' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler.setRemoveOnCancelPolicy(Z)V
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:591)
    ... 73 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler.setRemoveOnCancelPolicy(Z)V
    at org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurationSupport.messageBrokerSockJsTaskScheduler(WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurationSupport.java:96)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.DelegatingWebSocketMessageBrokerConfiguration$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$8bcc47d8.CGLIB$messageBrokerSockJsTaskScheduler$11(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.DelegatingWebSocketMessageBrokerConfiguration$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$8bcc47d8$$FastClassByCGLIB$$f696e179.invoke(<generated>)
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:215)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:280)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.DelegatingWebSocketMessageBrokerConfiguration$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$8bcc47d8.messageBrokerSockJsTaskScheduler(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
    ... 74 more


java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:157)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:109)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:321)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:211)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:290)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:24)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:157)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:74)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:211)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:67)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'stompWebSocketHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/web/socket/config/annotation/DelegatingWebSocketMessageBrokerConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping]: Factory method 'stompWebSocketHandlerMapping' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'messageBrokerSockJsTaskScheduler' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/web/socket/config/annotation/DelegatingWebSocketMessageBrokerConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler]: Factory method 'messageBrokerSockJsTaskScheduler' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler.setRemoveOnCancelPolicy(Z)V
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:602)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1113)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1008)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:505)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:229)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:762)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:103)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:1)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(DelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:228)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.loadApplicationContext(TestContext.java:124)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:148)
    ... 35 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping]: Factory method 'stompWebSocketHandlerMapping' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'messageBrokerSockJsTaskScheduler' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/web/socket/config/annotation/DelegatingWebSocketMessageBrokerConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler]: Factory method 'messageBrokerSockJsTaskScheduler' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler.setRemoveOnCancelPolicy(Z)V
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:591)
    ... 51 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'messageBrokerSockJsTaskScheduler' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/web/socket/config/annotation/DelegatingWebSocketMessageBrokerConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler]: Factory method 'messageBrokerSockJsTaskScheduler' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler.setRemoveOnCancelPolicy(Z)V
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:602)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1113)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1008)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:505)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:229)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:292)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.DelegatingWebSocketMessageBrokerConfiguration$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$8bcc47d8.messageBrokerSockJsTaskScheduler(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurationSupport.stompWebSocketHandlerMapping(WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurationSupport.java:51)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.DelegatingWebSocketMessageBrokerConfiguration$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$8bcc47d8.CGLIB$stompWebSocketHandlerMapping$9(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.DelegatingWebSocketMessageBrokerConfiguration$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$8bcc47d8$$FastClassByCGLIB$$f696e179.invoke(<generated>)
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:215)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:280)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.DelegatingWebSocketMessageBrokerConfiguration$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$8bcc47d8.stompWebSocketHandlerMapping(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
    ... 52 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler]: Factory method 'messageBrokerSockJsTaskScheduler' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler.setRemoveOnCancelPolicy(Z)V
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:591)
    ... 73 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler.setRemoveOnCancelPolicy(Z)V
    at org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurationSupport.messageBrokerSockJsTaskScheduler(WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurationSupport.java:96)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.DelegatingWebSocketMessageBrokerConfiguration$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$8bcc47d8.CGLIB$messageBrokerSockJsTaskScheduler$11(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.DelegatingWebSocketMessageBrokerConfiguration$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$8bcc47d8$$FastClassByCGLIB$$f696e179.invoke(<generated>)
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:215)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:280)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.DelegatingWebSocketMessageBrokerConfiguration$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$8bcc47d8.messageBrokerSockJsTaskScheduler(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
    ... 74 more


Process finished with exit code 255
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have inconsistent dependencies on your classpath.  Based on the stacktrace when Spring is loaded it can't find the `ThreadPoolTaskScheduler.setRemoveOnCancelPolicy()` method.  Check the jars on your classpath and see if you have an old version of certain Spring jars.  Most likely there is an old Spring jar that contains that class (without the method) on your classpath and it is being picked up first.

This could be because the jar is being included through a transitive dependency.  If you are using Maven, you can make sure all of your spring jars are consistent by using the Spring BOM pom.

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-framework-bom</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.3.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

If using gradle you can do something like:

```
configurations.all {
  resolutionStrategy {

    // add a dependency resolve rule
    eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
      //specifying a fixed version for all libraries with 'org.springframework' group
      if (details.requested.group == 'org.springframework') {
          details.useVersion'4.1.3.RELEASE'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution here and it works for me.

https://github.com/rstoyanchev/spring-websocket-portfolio/issues/21

You just need to add these dependencies into your pom.xml.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.8</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-websocket</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.8</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: did u work with an embeded tomcat ? is it spring boot ?

Comment: I have tyrus standalone client. Is it necessary to add tomcat websocket client?

Comment: I had the same issue and this solved it, but needed to set `<version>8.5.4</version>` since `8.5.4` is no longer supported https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/6890

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to add the most updated dependencies: 
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-websocket/5.2.4.RELEASE